# Metadata in WCC UCM : for one document, how to use several values from a business table as metadata?

Tags: foreign-keys, many-to-many, metadata, webcenter, oracle-ucm

We have a `BUSINESS_TABLE` with `ID, NAME, FIELD1, FIELD2, ...., FIELDn`.

In WCC, we want to link the docs to several items from the `BUSINESS_TABLE` (eg: `Document_1` is related to `id_1`, `id_2`, `id_455`, `id_456`, and so on), and these values have to be indexed, so we can run queries on this data from WCC.

Our first idea was to list these values in a custom metadata of type memo (`xLinkedBusinessItems = id_1, id_2, id_455, ......`)
But the memo type is limited to 1000 chars, what is not enough for our need.
(We know how to extend the memo to 4000 chars, but even so, it is not enough.)

Do you have an idea ? How can we tackle this feature ?

Thanks.